# Can we approximate a bounded upper semicontinuous function by increasing continuous sequences?

Tags: real-analysis

Can we approximate a bounded upper semicontinuous function by increasing continuous sequences? Even though the inverse question is obvious.

Comment: You you mean sequences of functions? By increasing do you mean that each function is increasing?

Comment: Yes. It means increasing continuous functions